# The code is giving an error after I gave a get update, but only in the execution of the code that gives the error

Tags: flutter, dart

My project is working normally but I updated it and now I have 4 errors

In Windows

Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Building Windows application...
../../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_calendar-20.4.54/lib/src/calendar/sfcalendar.dart(10776,71): error G44692867: A value of type 'RenderAbstractViewport?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'RenderAbstractViewport' because 'RenderAbstractViewport?' is nullable and 'RenderAbstractViewport' isn't. [C:\Users\YuriVittori\Documents\MeusProjetos\Project_002_Italian_Citizenship\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker-20.4.54/lib/src/date_picker/date_picker.dart(7596,37): error GC2F972A8: The argument type 'ScrollableState?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ScrollableState' because 'ScrollableState?' is nullable and 'ScrollableState' isn't. [C:\Users\YuriVittori\Documents\MeusProjetos\Project_002_Italian_Citizenship\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker-20.4.54/lib/src/date_picker/date_picker.dart(7611,40): error G44692867: A value of type 'ScrollableState?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ScrollableState' because 'ScrollableState?' is nullable and 'ScrollableState' isn't. [C:\Users\YuriVittori\Documents\MeusProjetos\Project_002_Italian_Citizenship\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
../../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker-20.4.54/lib/src/date_picker/date_picker.dart(7665,71): error G44692867: A value of type 'RenderAbstractViewport?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'RenderAbstractViewport' because 'RenderAbstractViewport?' is nullable and 'RenderAbstractViewport' isn't. [C:\Users\YuriVittori\Documents\MeusProjetos\Project_002_Italian_Citizenship\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): error MSB8066: o build personalizado para 'C:\Users\YuriVittori\Documents\MeusProjetos\Project_002_Italian_Citizenship\build\windows\CMakeFiles\dcdd952d1c4702d54d9b0fb6b7c2e1ef\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\Users\YuriVittori\Documents\MeusProjetos\Project_002_Italian_Citizenship\build\windows\CMakeFiles\7f5bf08d74bca50730b6e8b24c8b61f4\flutter_assemble.rule;C:\Users\YuriVittori\Documents\MeusProjetos\Project_002_Italian_Citizenship\windows\flutter\CMakeLists.txt' foi encerrado com o c�digo 1. [C:\Users\YuriVittori\Documents\MeusProjetos\Project_002_Italian_Citizenship\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.

In Chrome

Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
../../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_calendar-20.4.54/lib/src/calendar/sfcalendar.dart:10776:71: Error: A value of type 'RenderAbstractViewport?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'RenderAbstractViewport' because 'RenderAbstractViewport?' is nullable and 'RenderAbstractViewport' isn't.

- 'RenderAbstractViewport' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart' ('../../../Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/viewport.dart').
  RenderAbstractViewport get _stackViewPort => RenderAbstractViewport.of(this);
  ^
  ../../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker-20.4.54/lib/src/date_picker/date_picker.dart:7596:37: Error: The argument type 'ScrollableState?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ScrollableState' because 'ScrollableState?' is nullable and 'ScrollableState' isn't.
- 'ScrollableState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart' ('../../../Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart').
  scrollableState: Scrollable.of(context),
  ^
  ../../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker-20.4.54/lib/src/date_picker/date_picker.dart:7611:40: Error: A value of type 'ScrollableState?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ScrollableState' because 'ScrollableState?' is nullable and 'ScrollableState' isn't.
- 'ScrollableState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart' ('../../../Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart').
  ..scrollableState = Scrollable.of(context)
  ^
  ../../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker-20.4.54/lib/src/date_picker/date_picker.dart:7665:71: Error: A value of type 'RenderAbstractViewport?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'RenderAbstractViewport' because 'RenderAbstractViewport?' is nullable and 'RenderAbstractViewport' isn't.
- 'RenderAbstractViewport' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart' ('../../../Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/viewport.dart').
  RenderAbstractViewport get _stackViewPort => RenderAbstractViewport.of(this);
  ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your logs, it looks like you updated some packages (`syncfusion_flutter_calendar` and `syncfusion_flutter_datepicker`) but your current flutter version is older, because the errors you are showing point to a null-safety issues.

Please run in your console `flutter doctor` and post the result.
Also make sure to do in the console a `flutter clean`, followed by a `flutter pub get`

Comment: I ran flutter clean and flutter pub get, this is flutter doctor results

Comment: C:\Users\YuriVittori\Downloads\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.19044.2728], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 3.0.1 at C:\Users\YuriVittori\Downloads\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision fb57da5f94 (10 months ago), 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700
    • Engine revision caaafc5604
    • Dart version 2.17.1
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

Comment: [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\YuriVittori\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

Comment: [√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.2)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.4.33122.133
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

Comment: [√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

Comment: [√] VS Code (version 1.76.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\YuriVittori\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.60.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.19044.2728]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 111.0.5563.65
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 110.0.1587.69

Comment: [√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!

Comment: run in your console `flutter upgrade`  and once its finished, run again flutter clean, flutter pub get

Comment: It's taking time to run flutter pub get

Comment: It kind of worked, now I have an error in the code but at least it's running, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @DuasVias glad I could help, if you are satisfied with the answer you can mark it as chosen! Thank you